# Method invocation failed because X does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I made a script to analyse the AD I'm working on on daily basis.

It used to work fine for the past few months, with no error, but this morning one appeared and I can't figure out why.

It's during this execution:

```
$adm_disabled = ((Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(admincount=1)" | Where {$_.enabled -ne $true}).count) - 2
Write-Host "ADMIN ACCOUNTS DISABLED : "$adm_disabled
```

And I get the following error (that I never had before, it's in French btw) :

```
Échec lors de l’appel de la méthode, car [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] ne contient pas de méthode nommée « op_Subtraction ».
Au caractère D:\Users\pmonties\OneDrive - Professional\Documents\Scripts_PS_Test\ANALYSE_AD.ps1:29 : 1
+ $adm_disabled = ((Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(admincount=1)" | Where {$_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (op_Subtraction:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Translated

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
At D:\Users\pmonties\OneDrive - Professional\Documents\Scripts_PS_Test\ANALYSE_AD.ps1:29 : 1
+ $adm_disabled = ((Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(admincount=1)" | Where {$_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (op_Subtraction:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I don't get it, why does subtraction suddenly not work?

Comment: Maybe `Get-ADUser | ?...` doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says *"subtraction from an object of type `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection]` is impossible"*.

This type of error always occurs when you try to do arithmetics on something that does not support arithmetics:

```
# fails the same way:
@() - 2
```

In your case, you do

```
(($something).count) - 2
```

Independently of what `$something` is, your expectation is that `.Count` would be the count of those things, and therefore a number.

But what would happen if `$something` by accident would have an *own* property named `Count`? Then PowerShell will prefer to give you that property, and if it was not a number, but an `ADPropertyValueCollection`, the error above would occur.

```
$a = @{ some = "object" }
$b = @{ some = "object"; Count = 1,2,3 }

$a.Count - 2 # succeeds
$b.Count - 2 # fails with "[System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'
```

To prevent this, you could use `Measure-Object`, which returns a `MeasureInfo`, which has a numeric `Count`:

```
($something | Measure-Object).count - 2
```

Comment: By the way, you can query "disabled or not" directly with the LDAP query, that's more efficient than fetching all users and using `Where-Object`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46575050/i-need-to-find-out-disabled-users-from-ldap

Answer (score 2):

Forget my earlier response.  I think I managed to find the root cause.

I limited the results of the Get-ADUser so that after the Where-filter, I was left with 1 user.  And that user does not have a count property, because it's just 1 object.

```
#limit Get-ADUser using array notation [0..1]
$adm_disabled = ((Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(admincount=1)")[0..1] | Where {$_.Enabled -ne $true}).Count - 2
```

By simply adding an @-symbol, indicating I'm working with an array, it was working again.

```
$adm_disabled = @(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(admincount=1)" | Where {$_.Enabled -ne $true}).Count - 2
```

Comment: Works ! I get the mistake now, it was indeed because my get-aduser call was returning one single user. I will validate the other answer because it's more detailed but works greatly ! Thanks a lot

Comment: I also like the other answer better ;-)